# How do I write this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a table that records a history of child items linked to a parent, with two columns:

- ParentId
- ChildId

Some example data looks like this:

ParentId -- ChildId
001      -- 001
001      -- 001
001      -- 001
001      -- 002
001      -- 002
001      -- 002
001      -- 003
001      -- 003
001      -- 003
001      -- 003
001      -- 004
001      -- 004
001      -- 005
001      -- 005
001      -- 005
001      -- 005

I need to select all the rows with the highest value ChildId for a given ParentId. So in the above example, I need the query to return the following rows, given an input parameter of '@parentId = 001':

001      -- 005
001      -- 005
001      -- 005
001      -- 005

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't meant to do your work for you, rather to help you do your work.

Comment: I realise that, and ive been trying at this most of the afternoon!

Comment: My guess is it needs a nested query with an order by and select top 1, but i just cant seem to get the syntax right ..

Comment: Why is id 001 a parent to itself, 3 times? Won't that cause a loop? Beneath 001, you also have 001, which has another 001 beneath it, and then another beneath that, and ...?

Comment: because the relationship is actually a bit more complicated - parent -> child -> grandchildren. and I know the tables could and should be better designed, but i didnt build the system and dont have the luxury of changing them :o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This aught to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE parentId = '001'
AND childId = (SELECT MAX(childId) FROM MyTable WHERE parentId = '001')
```

Comment: Problem with this is when there are multiple different parentId's.

Comment: @dar7yl - The problem with the group by solution is that (as MalcomTucker mentioned) it will only return one row rather than all the matching rows like he wanted.

Comment: @Matthew Jones - yes, this would only work with one parent id (but that's all he wanted anyways)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT ParentID, MAX(ChildID) AS ChildID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ParentID
```

**Updated to edit missed requirement to return all rows:**

***Test Data***

```
-- Populate Test Data
CREATE TABLE #table (
  ParentID varchar(3) NOT NULL, 
  ChildID varchar(3) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','001')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','001')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','001')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','002')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','002')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','002')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','003')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','003')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','003')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','003')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','004')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','004')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','005')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','005')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','005')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('001','005')
```

***Results***

```
-- Return Results
DECLARE @ParentID varchar(8)
SET @ParentID = '001'

SELECT T1.ParentID, T1.ChildID
FROM #table T1
JOIN (
    SELECT Q1.ParentID, MAX(Q1.ChildID) AS ChildID
    FROM #table Q1
    GROUP BY ParentID
) ParentChildMax ON ParentChildMax.ParentID = T1.ParentID AND ParentChildMax.ChildID = T1.ChildID
WHERE T1.ParentID = @ParentID
```

Note: The performance of this solution is identical to the accepted solution (according to SQL Server profiler) using the following statement in the WHERE clause. But I like my solution better as it seems cleaner to me and can be easily extended to include other ParentIDs is required. (For example, reporting purposes.)

```
(SELECT MAX(childId) FROM #table WHERE parentId = @ParentID)
```

Comment: @daryl: It is very much not the right answer. This answer only returns one row. OP was looking to return *every* row that meets this criteria.

Comment: @eric - ah, you are right. But a simple join to the original table returns the correct data using ParentID and ChildID as the key. Using this method you are not limited to only looking at '001' but can get the max for all ParentIDs. The selected answer would be better enhanced if the SELECT MAX() subquery was correlated with the main table, extending the usefulness of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE parentId = '001'
AND childid = (select MAX (ChildId) 
               from TABLENAME
               where parentId = '001')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE ParentId = @parentId
GROUP BY ParentId
HAVING ChildId = MAX(ChildId)

Answer (score -1):

To cater for multiple parents in the table, the following should help

```
select parentId, max(childid) as ChildId
from <table_name>
group by parentId
```

Comment: this (and beach's answer) is the better solution

Comment: How is the solution presented by Breach (using a table join any better than a simpler "GROUP BY" statement?